# How can I make changing text with Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code to get some text from Firebase Database

```
var reviewID = 0;
var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("reviews/" + reviewID);

function getReview() {
    dataRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
        const reviewName = snapshot.val().name;
        const reviewText = snapshot.val().text;
        const reviewDate = snapshot.val().date;

        $('#reviewName').html(reviewName);
        $('#reviewText').html(reviewText);
        $('#reviewDate').html(reviewDate);
    });
};

getReview();
```

And I have this structure in Firebase.

[image]

I want button to change `reviewID` so I must get different values of `reviewName`, `reviewText` and `reviewDate`. Here is code for this button:

```
$('#reviewButtonRight').click(function () {
    reviewID += 1;
    getReview();
});
```

But it doesn't work. So how can I fix it?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: @BenSteward No, just nothing happens

Comment: Well that’s a bummer.

Comment: What you can do is to, use the `runOnThreadUI()`, and call the `firebase api` again, just make sure the `id is +1` every time you call the firebase, and `run it till the length of the id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new ref each time

```
var reviewID = 0; 
var reviewRef = firebase.database().ref("reviews"); 

function getReview() {
  const review = reviewRef.child(reviewID);
  review.once("value").then(function (snapshot) { 
    const reviewName = snapshot.val().name; 
    const reviewText = snapshot.val().text; 
    const reviewDate = snapshot.val().date; 
    $('#reviewName').html(reviewName); 
    $('#reviewText').html(reviewText); 
    $('#reviewDate').html(reviewDate); 
  }); 
}; 

getReview();
```